# Qt QML Mediaplayer Source Address for root file system

Tags: qt, video, qml

I try to play video using QML Mediaplayer. My Qt version is 5.3.1 and the code I use is:

```
 MediaPlayer {

       id: mediaplayer
       source: ./video.mp4
       loops: MediaPlayer.Infinite

       onError: {
           console.debug("mediaplayer video error\n");
           console.debug(errorString);
       }

       onPlaying: {
           console.debug("mediplayer plays, hasVideo: ", hasVideo, "\n");
           console.debug("videoplayer source address: ", source, "\n");
       }
     }
```

I want to play the video which is located under the directory same with the Qt app. But when the playback starts I get:

**mediplayer plays, hasVideo: false
 videoplayer source address: qrc:///video.mp4**

I have tried to give source path like this:

```
source: Qt.resolvedUrl("./video.mp4")
```

but the result doesn't change.

If I try to play video from qrc by giving the source url as:

```
source: "qrc:///video.mp4"
```

it logs:

**mediplayer plays, hasVideo: false
 videoplayer source address: qrc:///video.mp4**

but video doesn't playback. How can I manage to make mediaplayer's "hasVideo: true" to play it?

Comment: have you added your video to qt resources?

Comment: i suggest use QtCreator context menu element "Copy resource path to Clipboard" in Qt Resource Editor. It seems to me, that resource path you provided is not correct (also seems to me it should be just "video.mp4")

Comment: I had tried that too, but it did not work.